# /Tab index not working between User Control and a normal control

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i have a wpf user control and wpf textbox control in a page, when i pressed on Tab in keyboard it's not going to next control which is a normal textbox. i had set the property Tabstop to true but nothing worked...

I have not created any special property for tab index in user control.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  //(User Control)
  <controls:UserControl x:Name="txt_Name" Header="Name"/>  

   (Normal TextBox Control)
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
      <Label Content="Size" VerticalAlignment="Top" />  
      //(Normal TextBox Control)                       
      <TextBox Name="txt_sizeofFacility"/>
  </StackPanel>


  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
     <Label Content="Age" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
     //(Normal TextBox Control)
     <TextBox Name="txt_ageofFacility"/>
  </StackPanel>

    //(User Control)
  <controls:UserControl x:Name="txt_primaryActivity"  Header="Primary Activity"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I have copied you code and I cant reproduce it... pressing tab works just fine. could you be more specific?

Comment: try to focus manually on `txt_sizeofFacility` and press Tab what's happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <!--//(User Control)-->
    <controls:UserControl1 x:Name="txt_Name" />

    <!--(Normal TextBox Control)-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
        <Label Content="Size" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <!--//(Normal TextBox Control)-->
        <TextBox Name="txt_sizeofFacility"/>
    </StackPanel>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
        <Label Content="Age" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <!--//(Normal TextBox Control)-->
        <TextBox Name="txt_ageofFacility"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--//(User Control)-->
    <controls:UserControl1 x:Name="txt_primaryActivity"  />
</StackPanel>
```

And this is the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabIndex.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="test"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I can reproduce. Tab works even after setting focuse manually in each textbox

Comment: where can i set focus whether in design or code behind?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to set item focused not by clicking on it?

Comment: Actually i dont want to click, if i just pressing the Tab the cursor should move to next control whether its an user control or normal control.

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't set the initial focused item. try and set an item as focused on load.

Comment: For example type txt_sizeofFacility.Focus(); in you Window.loaded event

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that you can set the property below on the user control and that worked for me.

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
```